# Express middleware and parameter handling ordering on route

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

So I am running some API tests and I noticed that one test is failing because it is running some parameter handling logic before middleware, now here is an example of the route definition:

```
app.post("/something/:some_param",
    middlewareA, middlewareB, middlewareC,
    function(req, res) {
        // Do stuff
    });
```

Now I assumed (wrongly I think) that middleware would be invoked first then it would handle the parameter handler for `:some_param` however it seems to be the other way around. *(by parameter handler I mean app.param())*

Problem I have here is that if the above is correct and parameter handlers are run first, some of the logic within the parameter handler assumes the user is logged in already and blows up if they are not, and `middlewareA` handles user authentication and if they are not logged in redirects them etc, so ideally I would want middlewareA to be called first, so is there a way to achieve this ordering?

The only way I could see this working would be if the parameter handler could utilize middleware but there is no documentation on the API docs on this subject, so is there any best practice to handle this sort of scenario? as I do not want to have to shoe horn my `middlewareA` logic into my `:some-param` handling logic as I also have many other `:other-param` handlers etc which would also need this authentication (and other) middleware run before they run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, param handlers run before middleware. You can deal with this by either:

- recoding your param handler as a middleware. There's not that much difference between the 2 mechanisms.
- OR, in your param handler, just run the desired middleware directly as below:

.

```
function someParam(req, res, next, paramValue) {
  myAuthMiddleware(req, res, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      next(error);
      return;
    }
    //Here the user will be logged in
    // do what you need to do with req and paramValue
    next();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was not sure if middleware was supported as an optional argument but there was no docs on the subject, but just embedding it in the call should be enough for now unless I get more middleware needed to be ran.